# Assets != Equity + Liabilities

Tags: stocks, accounting, equity, balance-sheet

could anyone explain to me, in this balance sheet, which items are assets, which items are liability, and which items are equity?

Are funding debt and Notes issued liability?

Is redeemable convertible preferred stock equity?

I just feel Assets != Equity + Liabilities here. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are funding debt and Notes issued liability?

Yes

> Is redeemable convertible preferred stock equity?

Yes and No - from an accounting standpoint it is equity because it represents ownership (and shows up in the equity section of the balance sheet). However, financial analysts often value it like debt since it's typically bought for its fixed payout, not for its capital appreciation.

Note that the numbers you show don't balance in any combination - I suspect that the lines you show are a subset of the overall balance sheet and not intended to "balance".

Comment: Thanks. I do show the complete form. This is from "affirm" S1 report. The link is here:
https://investors.affirm.com/static-files/9f8aecad-266d-4956-b1fe-c8e720a06948
It is on page 80.

Comment: @JerryZhang I didn't mean to imply that you edited the data - I meant that the table is not a full balance sheet and does not balance - it's under "**SELECTED** CONSOLIDATED FINANCIAL AND OTHER DATA"

Comment: You can find more detail on page F-4 of that report.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I need to read the complete balance sheet.

Comment: Thanks. But even on page F-4, the numbers do not add up. For example, for the period ending on  June 30, 2020, total assets is $1,402,251, Total liabilities is 965,177 and Total stockholders’ deficit is (367,096). Assets != Equity + Liabilities

Comment: It balances if you also subtract the convertible shares (as if they were debt). Thast's why I said "yes and no". It's technically equity but is generally treated more like debt (in this case being excluded from common shareholder's equity)

Comment: Yes. You are right. Now, it balances. Thanks